# How to smooth/blur 2 similar images using opencv

Tags: opencv, blur, similarity

I am looking for a way to blur 2 images (somewhat noisy images, taken with the same equipment/setup but may have slightly different lighting) of two identical products (real products that is:) so the blurring kernel will consider the similar contours found in the two images.

I can find contours in both / one of the images, but what next?
In general I want to compare the images to find dissimilarities between them.
Any proposal?

Answer (score 1):

to find similarities or dissimilarities you can do the following..

1. Image registration...try to find number of features in both the images...the number of similar features found is a measure of how similar/dissimilar the images are...
2. If the two images are very similar except few details here and there....you can go ahead and find contours, number of contours and their lengths...any extra feature will produce extra contour...however this might not work for subjects which are same in both images but scaled or oriented differently in either image.
3. Grossly simplified but might prove effective... try to find the co-relation between two images...in this case smaller details might be skipped because the whole process is intensity based..

More detail of what kind of image or objects you are looking into will help solve your problem ...